# Check if is tablet on gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I am designing an app that should have its orientation fixed on portrait if running on a smartphone or fixed in landscape when on a tablet.

So I am trying to use manifest placeholders on the gradle file in order to set the screenOrientation attribute on the application's manifest. The problem is, I cannot verify the screen size on the gradle file. is there a way to check if it is a tablet on build.gradle? Or maybe I can achieve the same results doing something different?

Another thing that I tried was to use a boolean resource that I get from a resource file with the sw600dp qualifier. But android studio gives an error saying that it cannot reference a resource that vary by configuration on the manifest file.

Code:

**AndroidManiefst.xml**

    ...

```
<activity
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="${fixedOrientation}">
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    def portrait = 'portrait'
    def landscape = 'landscape'
    ...
    manifestPlaceholders.fixedOrientation = "$landscape"
}
```

fixedOrientation is currently static and I want to make it dynamic.

Comment: "is there a way to check if it is a tablet on build.gradle?" -- no. `build.gradle` is on  your development machine. It provides instructions for building your app for all devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you elaborate your comment as an answer so I can mark  as correct? If I need I will create a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to check if it is a tablet on build.gradle?

Not really.

`build.gradle` contains build instructions, nothing more. And, those build instructions are for building apps that could, in principle, go on a phone, tablet, TV, car, watch, or Jumbotron[1]

<sub>[1] you will need to supply your own Android-powered Jumbotron</sub>

The closest thing that Gradle would be involved with is if you wanted *different APKs*, one for phones, one for tablets. Then, Gradle would be involved in the setup of the product flavors needed to make those separate APKs. But I do not know how you would arrange for the distribution of one APK just to phones and the other APK just to tablets.

If Gradle is just building the one APK, then that one APK is for both phones and tablets, and so Gradle cannot know, at build time, whether any given user is using a phone or a tablet. Or a Jumbotron.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I kinda solved my initial problem by forcing the orientation through code. Not elegant but it works perfectly.

Comment: @JoãoPucci: If there is a single activity that needs this behavior, you could try `<activity-alias>`. Set up an alias for the activity. Have the activity use one `screenOrientation` and the alias use another. A `sw600dp` boolean resource can be used in `android:enabled`, so you would use the boolean resource to determine whether the activity or its alias is enabled for a given device. This probably gets annoying with lots of activities.

Comment: @CommonsWare there is no such method screen-orientation with <activity-alias> and it's not working. I am working on an app that works in a portrait in mobile and landscape mode on the tablet. I am facing a problem if mobile is in portrait mode, then the application load themed background in portrait mode and then change back to landscape. It looks like a glitch in the ui. I tried giving orientation in the theme, but its not working. Can you please suggest some solution for this.

Comment: @AshokSinghal: "there is no such method screen-orientation with <activity-alias> and it's not working" -- ah, sorry. "Can you please suggest some solution for this" -- no, because I have very little to go on. I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where your [mcve] explains how you are loading the background.